# How do I check checkbox state in C# Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I want to check my checkbox if checked. Windows forms it's ".Checked".
What code works similar with C#, working in Visual Studio for mac?

```
if (IgnoreErrorChk."Checked") {
    //ignore empty
    } else {
       throw new Exception("column exists already!"); }
```

The code asks for the checkbox, when the checkbox is checked, the programm will ignore errors while reading the csv into a mysql database.
If the columnname is already given, he will ignore the column and go to the next.

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do?

Comment: The code asks for the checkbox, when the checkbox is checked, the programm will ignore errors while reading the csv into a mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Check Box Button" is a `NSButton` with the type set to switch.

You can check is it is "on" via:

```
yourNSButtonInstance.State == NSCellStateValue.On
```

#### NSCellStateValue:

```
public enum NSCellStateValue : long
{
    Mixed = -1L,
    Off,
    On
}
```

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. On windows, these were so much easier. :D